# If Statement With 2 Arrays To Perfrom Relative Converging Task

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, if-statement, scripting

The data is fictional to keep it simple.

Here's the problem
Content Of Prcessed Data

```
cat rawdata

10 0-9{3}
4  0-9{3}
7  0-9{3}
```

noc=$(cat ipConn.txt | awk '{print $1}')
rct=$(cat ipConn.txt | awk '{print $2}')

Intended Solution:

for i in ${noc[*]}
  if $i -ge 50 then
    coomand -options ${rct[*]}
done

Is the code comprehensible??
but the item in ${noc[*]} must match the item in ${rct[*]}
so that only items in same line is affected..

Comment: Could you please post a sample of the intended output? In particular, should rows with first item less than 50 be discarded, or should they be left untouched in the output in the same order they are in the input file?

Comment: @Dario no, you got confused. Output should be as it is from command. Or maybe is better sorted. Task is that if item in 1st column equals or exceeds 50, I inted to run a command on item next to it in 2nd column.

Comment: Have you heard/tried `| while read -r num item; do ... done `?

Comment: @KamilCuk have tried but I can't figure out where it's lacking logic, let me update with that loop in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `while read` loop:

```
echo '10 0-9{3}
4  0-9{3}
7  0-9{3}' |
while IFS=' ' read -r num item; do
    if (( num >= 50 )); then
       some_action with "$item"
    fi
done
```

Note that the loop is typically very slow in bash. A faster solution would be to first filter the rows with first column greater or equal to 50, then remove the first column and then run some_action using xargs (or even pass `-P0` to xargs to run in parallel):

```
echo '10 0-9{3}
4  0-9{3}
7  0-9{3}' |
awk '$1 >= 50' |
cut -d' ' -f2- |
xargs -n1 some_action with
```

Comment: Thanks Kamil, you're genius.. thumbs up

Comment: Btw in 2nd code block you wrote, if I echo $1 it echoes both column, I wonder if it'll apply action on both columns

Comment: `xargs` is a little tricky, you can remove the first column with `cut` or `awk` or use `xargs -n1 -- sh -c 'shift; some_action with "$@"' --` or similar.